# Suggested Edits Queue for Mere Mortals

Tags: app, api-v2, editing

### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

### About

This Java command-line app gives you access to the [Suggested
Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) queue using the
[Stack Exchange 2.0 API](https://api.stackexchange.com/). It is ideally
suited for users in the `2000 <= reputation < 5000` range.

#### Usage

```
java -jar SuggestedEdits-XXXXXXXX/SuggestedEdits.jar <site> [duplicates_file]
```

#### Background

Access to the suggested-edits queue is typically earned after you cross
the 5000 rep threshold *even though* you're technically able to approve
or reject suggested-edits (after crossing 2000 rep). This program is my
silly little attempt at evening the playing field.

*Hint: There should be nothing stopping you from getting the
[Proofreader](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1276/proofreader) badge ;)*

#### License

Source code as well as binaries are released under the Apache License
Version 2.0 (full details
[here](https://github.com/marvinpinto/se-suggested-edits#license)).

#### Download Packages

- Zip: [SuggestedEdits-20120206.zip](https://github.com/downloads/marvinpinto/se-suggested-edits/SuggestedEdits-20120206.zip)
- Gzip: [SuggestedEdits-20120206.tar.gz](https://github.com/downloads/marvinpinto/se-suggested-edits/SuggestedEdits-20120206.tar.gz)
- Source code:
  [marvinpinto/se-suggested-edits](https://github.com/marvinpinto/se-suggested-edits)

#### Platform

Being a Java command-line app, pretty much any system with a functional
[Java Runtime Environment](http://www.java.com/getjava/) should have no
issues running this program.

#### Contributing

Please report issues on the [Github issue
tracker](https://github.com/marvinpinto/se-suggested-edits/issues). Patches
are preferred as Github pull requests. Please use topic branches when
sending pull requests rather than committing directly to master in order
to minimize unnecessary merge commit clutter.

*Please go through the README on
[Github](https://github.com/marvinpinto/se-suggested-edits) for the full
documentation including build instructions.*

Comment: is it possible to specify a proxy?

Comment: @oers Unfortunately no, I haven't added proxy support. But the source code is available so you're welcome to have at it :)

Comment: I just downloaded this, and it works great!  One thing I noticed: Leaving out the optional `[duplicates_file]` parameter causes the program to throw a `NullPointerException`.  So this works: `java -jar SuggestedEdits.jar stackoverflow dupes.txt`, but leaving off " dupes.text" causes the error.

Comment: @jadarnel27: I don't get it; On Physics.SE, I can view and review the suggested edits at 2k rep, without installing this.

Comment: @dimensio1n0 You can now. Back when suggested edits were first introduced, you couldn't; jadarnel27's comment had that context.

Comment: All of the download links seem to be broken.