# Anybody up for terminal frontends

Tags: discussion, app-request

Would anyone like to program some sort of terminal app which would be connected to a SE site?

You could query with it questions, and get notified when someone answers. Likewise one could browse other people's questions, etc.

I guess I could code it myself (and that it'd be fun!) but I'm involved in enough stuff already...

I hope someone gets inspired by the idea - and that this post is on topic.

Comment: I'm not sure what functionality you're looking for from this terminal app, but I've done two myself -- [here](http://stackapps.com/q/3087/9533) and [here](https://github.com/marvinpinto/se-question-hunter). The first one just gives you access to the suggested edits queue and the second one is akin to a _super_ filter for SE questions. Have fun :)

Comment: Whoa - the question hunter looks like a perfect, endless source of fun and self-improvement. Will leave feedback once I try it out!

Comment: A friend and I are actually planning on starting one tomorrow. It will be more general than Marvin's but I do love the SE questions one he wrote.